# comparing two 2D arrays and copying values to another 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first time to ask a question here.. I am not well versed with java and I am trying to implement an algorithm in java where I have to compare two 4rowsX3col 2D arrays with strings stored in them. I have to compare first row of 1st array to all the rows of second array and so on... and the values that are different must be copied to another 4X4 2D array in the following format.

```
Array1                            
b2 c1 e1 
b1 c3 e2 
b1 c1 e2 
b1 c3 e1 

Array2
b1 c1 e1 
b1 c1 e1 
b2 c2 e2 
b1 c2 e2

Resultant Array
b2           c3+e2      e2         c3
b2           c3+e2      e2         c3
c1+e1        b1+c3      b1+c1      b1+c3+e1
b2+c1+e1     c3         c1         c3+e1
```

How do I do it? I know how to compare them but i do not know how add them and copy to an array. Please help me!

I saw the comments and I am pasting my code and result below

```
import java.util.*;

public class Divide {

    // Input dataset
    String[][] dataset = new String[][] { { "b2", "c1", "e1", "d2" },
            { "b1", "c1", "e1", "d1" }, { "b1", "c3", "e2", "d2" },
            { "b1", "c1", "e1", "d1" }, { "b1", "c1", "e2", "d2" },
            { "b2", "c2", "e2", "d1" }, { "b1", "c3", "e1", "d2" },
            { "b1", "c2", "e2", "d1" } };

    String[][] dataset1 = new String[4][4];
    String[][] dataset2 = new String[4][4];

    String[][] discMatrix = new String[4][4];

    // Method to divide the dataset in to two matrices based on decision
    // attribute
    public void dividedMatrices() {
        int col = 3, row, i = 1, j = 0, k = 1, m = 0;
        System.arraycopy(dataset[0], 0, dataset1[0], 0, dataset[0].length);

        for (row = 1; row < dataset.length; row++) {
            if (dataset[0][3] == dataset[row][col]) {
                System.arraycopy(dataset[row], 0, dataset1[k], 0,
                        dataset[row].length);
                k++;

            } else {
                System.arraycopy(dataset[row], 0, dataset2[m], 0,
                        dataset[row].length);
                m++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Method to form Discernable matrix
    public void formDiscernablematrix() {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        String a = "";
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        // comparing the two datasets
        for (int i = 0; i < dataset1.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < dataset2.length; k++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataset1.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (dataset1[i][j] != dataset2[k][j]) {
                        temp.add(dataset1[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                for (int l = 0; l < temp.size(); l++) {
                    a = a + temp;
                }
                // copy a to disc matrix
                discMatrix[y][x] = a;
                y++;
                temp.clear();
                a = "";
            }
            x++;
            y = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(discMatrix));
    }
```

Result:

```
[[[b2],                                   [c3, e2][c3, e2],   [e2],               [c3]], 
 [[b2],                                   [c3, e2][c3, e2],   [e2],               [c3]], 
 [[c1, e1][c1, e1],                       [b1, c3][b1, c3],   [b1, c1][b1, c1],   [b1, c3, e1][b1, c3, e1][b1, c3, e1]], 
 [[b2, c1, e1][b2, c1, e1][b2, c1, e1],   [c3],               [c1],               [c3, e1][c3, e1]]]
```

I changed further. Below is my result. Could not get the "+" symbol though

```
[[[b2],         [c3, e2], [e2],     [c3]], 
 [[b2],         [c3, e2], [e2],     [c3]], 
 [[c1, e1],     [b1, c3], [b1, c1], [b1, c3, e1]], 
 [[b2, c1, e1], [c3],     [c1],     [c3, e1]]]
```

Comment: Post the code that you wrote so far, please. Show some effort.

Comment: How values from 4x3 are copied to 4x4 2D array? What should be copied to the 4th column? The question is unclear.

Comment: @ranifisch - It seems pretty clear from the example. The first column is the result of comparing the first row of `Array1` with each row of `Array2`; the second column is the result of comparing the second row of `Array1` with each row of `Array2`, etc.

Comment: Please be more clear

Comment: @DroidIcs It's perfectly clear.  See Ted Hopp's comment.

Comment: You're going to need three nested loops - the one to iterate through the rows of the first array, one to iterate through the rows of the second array, and the third one to iterate through the entries in each row, that you're comparing.  Within the second loop, you'll initialise a `String` or a `StringBuilder`, and within the third loop, you'll concatenate values to it.  I'm not going to write the code for you; but give it a try and comment again if you get stuck.

Comment: I posted the code. The method formDiscernablematrix() is the one I am referring to. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. @Ted Hopp - Thanks for the reply. I don't know if my logic is correct, but I don't think I can implement string concatenation in my code. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be concatenated using the `+` operator:

```
String string1 = "b1";
String string2 = "c3";
String result = string1 + "+" + string2; // result will be the string "b1+c3"
```

You can then assign the result to the appropriate element of the resultant array.

If you are going to be piecing together a string in increments (say, in a loop), it's more efficient to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and create the string at the end with a call to it's `toString()` method.